# how to return function with paramter from Immediately-invoked function expression(IIFE) jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to return function with paramter inside IIFE Syntax js function

and call it outside js

```
window.app = window.app || {};
window.app.test = app.test || {};

(function ($) {

    var getResult = function (result) {
        return result;
    };
    var handleError = function (result) {
        return result.responseText;
    };
    //data: "{ 'fileName':'"+ fileName +"' }",
     window.app.test.ReadFile = function (fileName) {

        var FileContents = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "~/helpers/FilesHelper.aspx/ReadAllContents",
            data: JSON.stringify({ fileName: fileName }),
            cache: false
        });

        FileContents.done(getResult).Fail(handleError);

    };


}(jQuery));
```

i call it like that

window.app.test.ReadFile("helpers.txt");

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f5tmnc4z/3/ ?

Comment: the problem was that i have syntax error you correct it

Comment: please add your answer so i can accept it and other can see instead of comment

Comment: @Mohamedabdelrahman still `Fail()` should be `fail()`. BTW, which syntax error are you talking about?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f5tmnc4z/4/

Comment: @A.Wolff syntax that was error i was assign
 window.app.test.ReadFile to function  inside  IIFE  and forgot to return result of function to caller

Comment: change the last line from `}(jQuery));` to `})(jQuery);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just return the function reference

```
window.app.test.ReadFile = (function ($) {

    var getResult = function (result) {
        return result;
    };
    var handleError = function (result) {
        return result.responseText;
    };
    //data: "{ 'fileName':'"+ fileName +"' }",
    return function (fileName) {

        var FileContents = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "~/helpers/FilesHelper.aspx/ReadAllContents",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                fileName: fileName
            }),
            cache: false
        });

        FileContents.done(getResult).fail(handleError);

    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: change function Fail to fail